# How to add custom HTML markup and classes to the_content()?

Tags: loop, the-content

I have HTML template for output from `the_content()` function. It contains elements with custom classes such as `<blockquote>`, headings or paragraphs.

```
<p class="mb-40">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit
    aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione
    voluptatem
    sequi nesciunt. 
</p>

<blockquote class="mb-40 bg-white">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-quote"></i>
    <p class="mb-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget mag
        dolor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
        et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus ru mus. Do quam felis ultricies nec
        pellentesque eu pretium quis sem. </p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: What is it you need help with? You should be able to paste this straight into the Editor in code/text view.

Comment: There is no option to pre-format HTML elements?

Comment: What do you mean, pre-format? As Bob answered, you can usually just target elements by their existing markup, without having to add classes. But in both the Classic Editor and the Block Editor, you can add the classes in the Editor if you really have a need to.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that should be handled in CSS without using classes, for examples

```
article blockquote {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Instead of adding `.bg-white` to the HTML tag. If you really want to add custom classes you could use a [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) or [get_the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) and parse it manually.